# Linear dependency of polynomials question

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to determine whether the polynomials $p_1(x)=2-x^2$, $p_2(x)=3x$, $p_3(x)= x^2 +x-2$ are linearly dependent or independent but I am not sure how to start. Anyone care to enlighten me?

Also I have to find out if it spans $P^{(2)}$.

Answer (score 15):

You need to know whether there are scalars $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$ not all $0$ such that $c_1p_1+c_2p_2+c_3p_3=0$.  So:
$$
\begin{align}
& c_1p_1(x)+c_2p_2(x)+c_3p_3(x) \\[6pt]
= {} & c_1 (2-x^2)+c_2(3x)+c_3(x^2+x-2) \\[6pt]
= {} & (c_3-c_1)x^2 + (3c_2 + c_3)x + 2(c_1-c_3) \\[6pt]
= {} & 0 \text{ for all }x.
\end{align}
$$
That means you need
$$
\begin{align}
c_3-c_1& =0 \\[6pt]
3c_2 + c_3 & =0 \\[6pt]
2(c_1-c_3) & =0
\end{align}
$$
The question is whether than can happen if at least one of the numbers $c_1,c_2,c_3$ is not $0$.  And the answer is "yes", as you should be able to figure out from there.  Therefore they are linearly dependent.

Three members of a $3$-dimensional vector space cannot span the space unless they're linearly independent.  (More than three can, in some cases.)

Comment: To save any future math students googling a head scratching moment: there's a multiplication/factoring issue. In particular, `3c2 = 0` is wrong. The `c3(x^2 + x - 2)` should have yielded another coefficient for x -- it should be `3c2 + 3c3 = 0`. The polynomials are still linearly dependent though.

Comment: May I ask why $c1$, $c2$ and $c3$ must not all be $0$?

Comment: @HarryStuart : Three vectors in a $3$-dimensional space span the space if and only if they are linearly independent. Showing that a nonzero solution exists in this case amounts to showing they are linearly dependent. So they cannot span the whole space.

Answer (score 10):

$\{1,x,x^2\}$ form a basis for the space of quadratic polynomials, and you can represent your polynomials as vectors in terms of this basis. Therefore you simply need to determine whether the matrix $$\left(\begin{matrix}-1 & 0 & 2\\0 & 3&0\\1&1&-2\end{matrix}\right)$$is invertible. Plainly it is not.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that $P^{(2)}$ represents all polynomials over some field of degree less than or equal to $2$, then your questions are the same, because the dimension of $P^{(2)}$ is $3$, so if the given polynomials are linearly independent, they must form a basis of $P^{(2)}$ and hence span it.

To answer the question of linear independence, we can associate each polynomial to a vector by taking it's leading coefficients.  The vectors obtained in this way are $(-1,0,2)$, $(0,3,0)$, and $(1,1,-2)$.  To see that these vectors are linearly independent, compute the determinant of the matrix they determine:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-1&0&2\\
0&3&0\\
1&1&-2
\end{pmatrix}$$

It turns out that the determinant of this matrix is zero, so the vectors are not linearly independent.  A dependence relation is given by:

$$3p_1(x)-p_2(x)+3p_3(x)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

We could do it "by inspection." Add the first and the third.

So we have $3$ vectors, not independent. They cannot span a $3$-dimensional space.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the problem this way: By definition, the linear independence of terms in a polynomial function is to show that
$$
k_0+k_1\cdot x+k_2\cdot x^2 +\cdots+k_n\cdot x^n=0.  \tag{1}
$$
only if $k_0, k_1, k_2, ..., k_n$ are all zero.  To show this is the case, take derivatives of $(1)$  successively up to the $n$th derivative; then we can form a system of homogeneous  linear equations for the $k$s. The coefficient matrix of the system of equations is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&      x&      x^2& \cdots&  x^{n-1}& x^n\\  
0&      1&      2x& \cdots&  (n-1)x^{n-2}&            nx^{n-1}\\  
0&      0&      2& \cdots&  (n-1)(n-2)x^{n-3}&    n(n-1)x^{n-2}\\  
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\\  
0&       0&      0&        \cdots&        0&                            n!\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The determinant of the above matrix is a product of all the diagonal elements, which is 2!3!...(n-1)!n!, obviously  not zero regardless of $x$. Therefore the only solutions for $k$s  are all zero. This proves the independence.

Comment: I did not expect that the matrix looks like a long line when it was posted. Actually each [ ...] is a row of the same matrix. I typed this post in my iphone.

Comment: How can I type math in this site? Using latex?

Comment: Yep, pretty much. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for more information.

Comment: It looks like someone has latexed my matrix above. Thanks! IIt looks much better now!

Comment: I am a new comer to this site and this is the first time I ever gave an answer to a posted question here. Could anyone tell me what does the number on th left between the upper and down arrow mean？ Does this mean a reputation score ？If so, why the number for my answer is -1？A minus reputation? Who score it?  It does not make sense! I think I have a very general answer to the question. If you do not see this way, please challenge me！Thanks！

Comment: Welcome to MSE! The number between the arrows is the net number of votes on your answer. People can click on the "up" arrow to "upvote" your answer to say that they like it, which will make that number go up by 1, or they can click on the "down" arrow to "downvote" your answer to say that they don't like it, which will make the number go down by 1. See https://math.stackexchange.com/tour and https://math.stackexchange.com/help for more information about how the site works.

Comment: It is rediculus that science is judged by democratic votes! Galileo Galilei was voted to death more than 300 years ago. Are you guys repeating the same absurdness in this modern age? Whoever puts a negative vote could well mean he is incompetent to understand a right answer, which is evidently the case to the vote to my answer.

Comment: The other answers above assumed that the questioner already knew how to prove that {1,x，x^2} was linearly indepdent. However this is likely not the case, otherwise he/she would not post the question of the same type.