# geometrical view of linear independence........

Tags: linear-algebra

if two or more polynomial equations cannot be expressed as a linear combination with constants say a,b,c... ,does it mean they are linearly independent.

my question is,if they are independent i.e,they will intersect or not(I am asking about geometrical view)

Comment: $x$ and $x^2$ are independent. Do they intersect?

Comment: Any polynomials can be put into a linear combination. Linear independence depends on there being a linear combination such that the sum is 0. Can you clarify the first paragraph of your question please?

Comment: For more info see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333186/linear-dependency-of-polynomials-question